# Set SLIP Between xenix and linux

Tags: linux

For study purpose i want to set a slip-serial tcp connection between a new linux machine and old xenix machine wich run on VirtualBox.
I've setup xenix Virtual Machine with two serial ports: one on /dev/ttyS0(host pipe) and the other on /tmp/xenixserial(file pipe),the second port tested with minicom is ok.
On linux i did

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
slattach -s 9600  -d -p slip  /dev/ttyS0
ifconfig sl0 192.168.7.1 dstaddr 192.168.7.2 netmask 255.255.255.252 mtu 576 up
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.7.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

On xenix i did

```
mkdev slip: only ask for relink kernel,of course answered yes
mkdev tcp:  and set 192.168.7.2 as local 192.168.7.1 as remote and tty1a 9600 for serial
```

On reboot i can see all works

```
sl0: flags=51<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING>                                                                                   
    inet 192.168.7.2 --> 192.168.7.1 netmask ffffff00
```

But no ping,neither from host to guest,no from guest to host.
I also tried to add route

```
    route add default 192.168.7.1 1
```

but nothing.
Suggestion?Thanks

Comment: Try first without the `iptables` rule. It might be interfering by trying to NAT the pings between the 2 hosts. Once you have local communication working between the hosts, then start introducing things like NAT as desired. By the way, one thing I notice is that the netmask is wrong: it shows `ffffff00` but it should be `fffffffc` which is equal to `255.255.255.252` which is the same as `/30` which is what you specified earlier. But typically it would work anyway despite that.

Comment: I wrote wrong netmask,sorry of course i have used same netmask 24 for all,but nothing to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found,TTYS0 is a driver/module wich point to an existing physical serial(enable on my motherboard).
To use a setup like this,must use the pty driver(pts/0,1,2,etc) but is not supported by virtualbox,qemu support it,if intersted here is the procedure.

On Qemu host

```
#run qemu,256m ram disk not over 512M,pc-bios important otherwise give error
#control wich pts is running qemu,you will must use later
qemu-system-i386  -serial pty -hda Xenix.disk -boot c -fda floppy.img -no-fd-bootchk -m 256  -L pc-bios

#ip_forward
echo 1 1>/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
#slattach
slattach -s 19200 -d -p slip /dev/pts/4 #pts/4 is used by qemu

#192.168.7.1 is on host,192.168.7.2 is guest
ifconfig sl0 192.168.7.1 dstaddr 192.168.7.2 netmask 255.255.255.252 mtu 576 up 
#enable routing iptables
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.7.0/30 -j MASQUERADE
```

On Xenix

```
mkdev slip #answer yes to all
reboot
mkdev tcp   #set 19200 serial speed and 192.168.7.2 ip,and correct netmask
```