# UART to UART tcp/ip connection

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, tty, serial-port, uart

Need to transmit and receive data(TCP/IP) between 2 raspberry through serial tx/rx pins (/ttyAMA0). Best way to do it? Better if this will be done from kernel space. Thanks!

Comment: Im looking for some SLIP machanism, but dont know how to use correct it in this situation

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187110/set-slip-between-xenix-and-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo slattach -p slip -s 115200 -v -d /dev/ttyAMA0 //both

sudo ifconfig sl0 192.168.11.245 pointtopoint 192.168.11.246 // mirror ip on client

//host config

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -A FORWARD -i sl0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o sl0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE